# PL/SQL Procedure - ignore argument if null

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure that takes three arguments and then queries a table based on those arguments. Now one of them could be null and if it is, I'd like it to be ignored in the WHERE clause of the selection.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Procedure1 
(
   COUNTRY IN VARCHAR2, MAKE IN VARCHAR2, SERIAL IN number
) AS

BEGIN

DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS  select v.ID from vehicle v   
                where v.country = COUNTRY AND 
                      v.make = MAKE AND 
                      ((SERIAL IS NOT NULL AND v.serial = SERIAL) OR 1);


BEGIN 

  FOR e_rec IN c1 LOOP

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(e_rec.id);

  END LOOP;

END;
END Procedure1;
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Using a parameter name that is identical to a column can lead to confusion, I would do that. I think your condition should look like this: `(SERIAL IS NULL or v.serial = SERIAL)`. I wouldn't be surprised if the PL/SQL parser actually uses the *column*  serial throughout that expression. Better change the parameter name, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I will take care to change the name of the parameter too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the condition like

```
WHERE v.country = COUNTRY AND 
                      v.make = MAKE AND 
                     (SERIAL IS NULL or v.serial = SERIAL)
```

This will also work

```
WHERE v.country = COUNTRY AND 
                  v.make = MAKE AND 
((SERIAL IS NOT NULL AND v.Serial = SERIAL) OR SERIAL IS NULL)
```

Comment: This works but I think the solution provided above is better: (SERIAL IS NULL or v.serial = SERIAL)

Answer (score 1):

try this - this is same as @Miller suggested just using NVL function

```
WHERE v.country = nvl(COUNTRY,v.country) 
AND v.make = nvl(MAKE,v.make)   
AND v.serial = nvl(SERIAL,v.serial)
```

Comment: It looks fine but it fails when `v.serial` is `null`, because `null = null` results in `unknown`.